# Postgres 13 and Failover Slots

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres HA solution using streaming replication and managed by Patroni.  I would like to also add logical replication.  In case of a failover from master to the slave, do I need to rebuild the logical replication from scratch, or the [Failover Slots](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/failover-slots-postgresql/) solution discussed by Craig Ringer was implemented in Postgres 13.

Comment: It seems the patch Craig is talking about in that blog post didn't make it into Postgres 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication slots only exist on the primary, and there is no high availability solution for them. You will have to rebuild the logical standby after a failover.

Comment: Thanks!  We use HA Proxy so we always point me to the current master.  Should I use inet_server_addr() to identify which server I'm pointing to and detect if failover occurred, or there is a better way to detect failover?